# How to add image in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I can't find the right syntax for supplying an image from a URL.

```
<image src='url(' +${this.url}+ ')'
                 style={{
                   height: 'auto',
                   width: '100%'
                 }}></image>
```

Can you give me a source to know when to use: `${}`,`{}`, ``, ""?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since html attributes cannot be concatenated like `myattr='my'+dynamic+'value` React provides us the curly brace to use dynamic value:

```
<image src={'url(' + this.url + ')'} />
```

Notice, concatenation is done inside the curly brace `{}`.

But today, we use ES6+ features mostly, thus concatenating them using `+` operator is an ugly solution. Hence, we use [template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) using tilde key <kbd>`</kbd>

```
<image src={`url${this.url}`} />
```

To use the variable inside the template literal, we use `${variable_name}`.

---

Further, I suspect the url() function here, have you defined anywhere? Otherwise, you should not use, just use:

```
<image src={this.url} />
```

The value of src is just a path to the image `src="path.jpg"` but not `src="url(path.jpg)"`.

Also, is image a component? Otherwise, it should be `<img />` tag not `<image />`. If `image` is a component, then I suggest you to use Capitalized name in your component even if they are functional component.

Comment: I don't see the image. When I do: `<div
            className="image-root responsive"
            style={{
              backgroundImage: `url(${this.url})`,
              height: 1000,
              width: 1000
            }}/>` it's working.

Comment: height width should have measure like 1000px.

Comment: Thanks for it still not working. I even tried: 
`<image src={`url${this.url)}`}
                 style={{
                   height: '1000px',
                   width: '1000px'
                 }}></image>`

Comment: You may try opening the broken image and see if path is fine.

Comment: It is because when I use it as a background image it's working fine.

Comment: Yes! I `Image` is not a component. By mistake, I used it instead of `img`. and also I thought that `url` function is needed here also because I used it in the background image also. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

In your case you should write:

```
<image src= {this.url}
             style={{
               height: 'auto',
               width: '100%'
             }}></image>
```

You use {} when there is a var, "" when it's a string, and ${} when you are inside backquote ``

Comment: why you omit the `url` function?

Comment: Because you don't need it. Unless url is one of your own function and you apply custom change on your url. But url is certainly a reserved word.

Answer (score 1):

`` use mostly for if you don't want to break your code  or string which mostly happen with `''` or `""` like this

```
console.log('string text line 1\n' +
'string text line 2');
```

solution use ``

```
console.log(`string text line 1
```

string text line 2`);

`${}` is used in `` and is equal to `+` in `''`

```
var a = "hello";
 console.log(`string text line 1 ${a}
string text line 2`);
```

`{}` is `JSON` syntax and used for `style` `object` which accept only `JSON` if you are adding inline

`""` is same to `''`

---

Just use `` rather than ''

```
 <image src= `${this.url}`
             style={{
               height: 'auto',
               width: '100%'
             }}></image>
```

Comment: Thank you. Can you also give me an answer for my specific problem with the image?

Comment: because the image is a URL from the internet and not on my local machine. or is it not matter?

Comment: No It does not matter you can use without `url()` We use `url()`  mostly when we are setting background-image using css.

Answer (score 0):

```
<image src={this.url}
           style={{
                   height: 'auto',
                   width: '100%'
                 }}></image>
```

and if it's in the props you put `{this.props.url}`

Answer (score 0):

All your javascript code should be inside `{}` operators when writing jsx.

`${}` is used when you are using [template literal syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) i.e. ``.

```
<image url = {`url(${this.url})`} />
```

Answer (score 0):

use template literals [reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

```
<image src= {`${this.url}`}
             style={{
               height: 'auto',
               width: '100%'
             }}></image>
```

Comment: this syntax is not legal: `src= `${this.url}`` and I get warning from eslint: `Parsing error: JSX value should be either an expression or a quoted JSX text`